# Applicable of Spring Annotation in different layers

Tags: java, spring

As Spring has the annotation `@Component` to represent any Spring manage component. Then again we use `@Controller` to in a MVC controller bean. But What extra advantage i get use `@Controller` over `@Component`? If we use `@Controller` instead of `@Component` is it for more clarity on layers or is there any additional support give by Spring?

Answer (score 0):

The @Controller is used specifically used in SpringMVC and indicates that the annotated class has the role of a controller, and this in turn allows the Spring DispatcherServlet to identify potential handlers for requests to the particular service.

When the DispatcherServlet receives a request, it delegates it to the appropriate controller, based on its @RequestMapping and @Controller values.

@Component indicates that the class itself should be managed by the Spring container.

Both are similiar in the fact they are discovered by the classpath scanning.